# Eclipse CDT does not correctly parse 'unsigned int myVar;'

Tags: eclipse-cdt

I encounter strange problem with Eclipse CDT Helios under Ubuntu
The screen shot is here https://i.stack.imgur.com/xaDVv.jpg

```
int MiniMsg::parseChecksum() {

   unsigned int dint; // this if flagged as syntax error by Eclipse only!!
   uint32_t  d32;

   return parseItem(chkStart, chkEnd, checksum);
```

}

The definition of 'dint' is not recognized and flagged as syntax error.
Actually any definition of the form 'signed/unsigned type var' is not recognized...

Any ideas?

Comment: What is the actual syntax error you are seeing?

Answer (score 0):

Usually a yellow squiggly means a compiler warning, and guessing by the fact that that variable is never used, it is probably complaining about that.

The warning would be something along the lines of:

foo.c:3: warning:  'unsigned int dint' defined but not used

Comment: Nope, this is not question of used/unused... If i remove 'unsigned' or 'int' the syntax error ntofication disappear!!!!

Comment: I've just discovered it actually happnes only in ONE project!!!!  Other  C++ projects are ok!?